# Make ReadFile() return as soon as something has been read

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

I want to read data from the serial port in a consistent manner on both Linux and Windows. I've noticed that `read()` and `ReadFile()` behave a little differently. Consider the following code:

```
// on Linux
int r = read(fd, buf, 256);

// on Windows
ReadFile(handle, buf, 256, &r, NULL);
```

Both functions will block forever until data arrives. So far, so good. However, there is a little difference: `read()` will return as soon as at least 1 byte arrives whereas `ReadFile()` will not return before all 256 bytes have arrived.

Thus, I'd like to ask: Is there a way to make `ReadFile()` behave like `read()` on Linux, i.e. return as soon as at least 1 byte is there even though 256 have been requested?

Comment: Why can't you just use `read()` with your windows code, too?

Comment: I'm using `librs232` which uses the native Windows API.

Comment: Change the 3rd parameter to `1` and read in a loop until you have 256 bytes.

Comment: Sounds like the workaround in case there is no other way to do it :)

Comment: Also, IIRC, you can use `COMMTIMEOUTS` to set all the timeout values to `0`.

Comment: The timeouts are already set to 0, that's why it's blocking forever, which is what I want but it should stop blocking as soon as 1 byte arrives.

Comment: you need call [`SetCommTimeouts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_commtimeouts)  - *If an application sets ReadIntervalTimeout and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier to MAXDWORD and sets ReadTotalTimeoutConstant to a value greater than zero and less than MAXDWORD, one of the following occurs when the ReadFile function is called:

If there are any bytes in the input buffer, ReadFile returns immediately with the bytes in the buffer.
If there are no bytes in the input buffer, ReadFile waits until a byte arrives and then returns immediately.*

Comment: more info about different timeout combinations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddser/ns-ntddser-_serial_timeouts)

Comment: @RbMm: This looks like what I want except one thing: It's not possible to set it to block forever that way. I'd have to set `ReadTotalTimeoutConstant` to `MAXDWORD-1` to simulate "forever" but of course, strictly speaking, it's not forever, although probably acceptably forever :)

Comment: @Andreas In that case, try calling `ReadFile()` in a loop.  If any bytes are read, break the loop. Otherwise, if the read times out, call `ReadFile()` again to get a new timeout interval.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, that's a good idea.

Comment: @RbMm: Do you want to post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? I've tested it here and it does exactly what I want so it should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best approach is to implement the circular buffer, use the functions you like to read 1 byte from the stream place in the buffer and then call the receive callback function - or just poll the circular buffer for data presence.

It sorts out all of your problems - you will be notify (or you can poll for the data present) when the data arrives and will not overwrite the buffer (of course you need to read the data otherwise if the buffer is full you will be ignoring the new data)

Here you have a very simple implementation

```
unsigned char buff[128];

struct 
{
    unsigned head:8;
    unsigned tail:8;
}control = {.head = 0, .tail = 0};

int isFull(void)
{
    return (control.head + 1) == control.tail;
}

int isEmpty()
{
    return control.head == control.tail;    
}

int push(int ch)
{
    if(!isFull())
    {
        buff[control.head++] = ch;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int pop(void)
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        return buff[control.tail++];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And simple usage

```
void (*rcvcallback)(void);
initReceive(void (*callback)(void))
{
    rcvcallback = callback;
}

void receive(void)
{
    int r = 0;

    #ifdef LINUX
    read(fd, &r, 1);
    #endif

    #ifdef WINDOWS
    size_t size;
    ReadFile(handle, &r, 1, &size, NULL);
    #endif

    push(r);
    rcvcallback();
}

#ifdef WINDOWS
#define EL "\n\r"
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
#define EL "\n"
#endif


void myRCVcallback(void)
{
    printf("Byte received: %d"EL, pop());
}


int main()
{
    printf("Starting ......"EL);

    while(1)
    {
        receive();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DV? Interesting.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I prefer RbMm's solution of using `SetCommTimeouts()`, although that has the drawback of having to use a timeout of `MAXDWORD-1` but this should be acceptable because it corresponds to a timeout of 50 days or so :)